# Installation of Angular fails on Mac Catalina - Angular % sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular, typescript, macos, terminal

Version of my npm : 6.14.6
Version of node : v12.18.3
I have tried :

1. dded sudo in the beginning also but still not working.
2. Tried to install har-validator using command :  sudo npm install har-validator
3. Tried : npm install --force expo-cli -g

**** Angular % sudo npm install -g @angular/cli ****

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/Users/opshori/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /Users/opshori/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@10.1.2 postinstall /Users/opshori/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

- @angular/cli@10.1.2
  updated 1 package in 9.107s

Answer (score 0):

try npm cache clean -force, this delete cache